# Get or load URL action from a frame in timeline

Tags: flash, actionscript

I wold like to give a get or load URL action from a frame in timeline. 
Is this possible?

I tried below code

```
on enterFrame {
```

getURL("http://www.sample.com/", "_self");
}

but it doesn't work.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Mabye you can use `addFrameScript();`

which we type as :

```
addFrameScript(>>>>>frame number of layer<<<<, >>>function name<<<<);
```

**So lets suppose** (As you did not mention the frame number)

You want to load sample.com on frame 2 so the we will write this in your main document class in constructor function(This function has the same name as class name) :

```
addFrameScript(1, url);
```

Now you need to add the function too which will open the url

```
public function url():void
{
getURL("http://www.sample.com/", "_self"); 
}
```

If you are confused then you can do this way

[image]

And then enter

[image]

or even this is not working try this !

```
var url:String = "http://www.sample.com/";
var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url);
try {
  navigateToURL(request, '_self');
} catch (e:Error) {
  trace("Error occurred!");
}
```

I am also new in flash and did not test it but i am quite sure one of this would work